# Segmentation Fault when installing my package with pip3

Tags: python-3.x, segmentation-fault, pip

I am currently trying to install my [own package](https://github.com/ntchambers/cherrybomb) using the command: `pip3 install --user .`, which invokes this [setup script](https://github.com/ntchambers/cherrybomb/blob/master/setup.py). However, when I do that, I get the following output:

```
cherrybomb@cherrybomb:~/cherrybomb$ pip3 install --user .
Processing /home/cherrybomb/cherrybomb
Collecting twisted>=17.9.0 (from cherrybomb==0.1.0)
Collecting pyopenssl>=17.5.0 (from cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel>=0.30.0 (from cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached wheel-0.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting hyperlink>=17.1.1 (from twisted>=17.9.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached hyperlink-17.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting constantly>=15.1 (from twisted>=17.9.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Automat>=0.3.0 (from twisted>=17.9.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached Automat-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting incremental>=16.10.1 (from twisted>=17.9.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached incremental-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting zope.interface>=4.0.2 (from twisted>=17.9.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached zope.interface-4.4.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting cryptography>=2.1.4 (from pyopenssl>=17.5.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached cryptography-2.1.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting six>=1.5.2 (from pyopenssl>=17.5.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting attrs (from Automat>=0.3.0->twisted>=17.9.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached attrs-17.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools (from zope.interface>=4.0.2->twisted>=17.9.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached setuptools-38.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy" (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyopenssl>=17.5.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached cffi-1.11.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting idna>=2.1 (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyopenssl>=17.5.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyopenssl>=17.5.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
  Using cached asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"->cryptography>=2.1.4->pyopenssl>=17.5.0->cherrybomb==0.1.0)
Installing collected packages: hyperlink, constantly, six, attrs, Automat, incremental, setuptools, zope.interface, twisted, pycparser, cffi, idna, asn1crypto, cryptography, pyopenssl, wheel, cherrybomb
  Running setup.py install for cherrybomb ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-8wz3oeu9-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mxvris8y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-8wz3oeu9-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mxvris8y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code -11 in /tmp/pip-8wz3oeu9-build/
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
cherrybomb@cherrybomb:~/cherrybomb$
```

I am installing this on ubuntu 17.10 x64:

```
cherrybomb@cherrybomb:~/cherrybomb$ uname -a
Linux cherrybomb 4.13.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18:35:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
cherrybomb@cherrybomb:~/cherrybomb$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.3
cherrybomb@cherrybomb:~/cherrybomb$
```

Any insight into what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated. Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

Though this seems to be an old issue I hope leaving a reply here may be of help.

Try with `sudo !!`. If you weren't inside a virtual environment, maybe you didn't had the necessary privileges to install the packages system wide.

Comment: I had this issue with upgrading impacket.. sudo worked... I can't believe I didn't try that myself (facepalm). Thanks!